# Firebase Security Rules Regex in Path

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have security rule write like this :

```
 /databases/{database}/documents {

     match /collection_COUNTRY_EN/{docId} {
          allow....
     }

     match /collection_COUNTRY_ES/{docId} {
          allow... 
     }
}
```

Where the rule are identical to all the country. Is there a way to implement regex in the match /path to have the same rule for all the collection that start with something and end with a country code ? 
Or does i have to structure my data in a different way ?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Security rules do not support regex in the path match.  You can only wildcard on the full name of a path segment.

What you might want to do instead is organize all your common top-level collection into subcollections organized under a known document, and apply the same rules to each of them that way:

```
match /countries/data/{countryCollection}/{docId} {
    allow...
}
```

This would apply the same permissions to all country subcollections organized under /countries/data, which can be an empty document, or even a non-existent document.

Comment: Ok, that what i was thinking. 
I'm going with your solution since i should have a lot of country and don't want to have 50+ lines of the same rules...

Thanks you !